# How to get a user password form in Preprocess like user login

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

How to get a user password form in Preprocess like user login

```
$form = Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm::class);
$variables['login_form'] = $render->renderPlain($form);
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the form for changing password or?

Comment: I get The user password form for templating. Now how we can change username??

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your own function before from submit function to get form data

```
$form = Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(Drupal\user\Form\UserLoginForm::class);
// Add your own function before form submit here
$variables['login_form'] = $render->renderPlain($form);
```